# PHP MySQLi Stmt Prepare

Tags: php, mysql

How would I `mysqli::stmt->bind_param` something that's considered as `NULL` in mysql?

I'm currently using

```
$stmt->bind_param('s', 'NULL');
```

Comment: Is what you're using currently working? I assume it isn't, but is giving `NULL`? Have you tried a PHP `null` value?

Comment: When you use NULL in a query, you use `column IS [NOT] NULL`. You know when you have to use NULL, therefore you normally don't have to bind it to your query. As Pekka said, it would be good to tell us what you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bind_param passes variable as reference.

Try:

```
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param('s', $null);
```